# SceneKit: SKNode resolution on iOS

Tags: ios, 3d, resolution, scenekit, sknode

I am using a `.dae` file to create my `SCNNode`. The quality of my 3D object looks perfect when opening with the `.dae` file editor, or preview app, but it looks so poor on the `SCNNode` (screenshot's pixelated lines).

Does this issue have any solution or improvement? Is there any parameter I should set to fix that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your .dae file all those little bits and pieces modelled as objects? If so, I think you need to turn on Anti-Aliasing, that should solve this.

By default, this is turned off on iOS for performance reasons:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/SceneKit/Reference/SCNView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SCNView/antialiasingMode